# insert an admin table inside another admin page

Tags: wp-admin, wp-list-table

**Scenario** : I have a plugin already existing (not written by me) that have many admin page, and I'd like to modify one. One have a list of booking, the other one have a calendar, and I'd like to add the booking list at the bottom of the calendar.

First of all, could I retrieve the table using wordpress core api to insert it on the other page ?
If that's definitely not the case, I suppose I'll have to rewrite it and In that case, How Can I add a table somewhere in an admin page already existing ?

I assume this question is really dependent of the way the plugin was written over wordpress api and since I'm not that used to it, I can't really answer this question directly. I can however tell that the admin pages use a lot of action/filter that seem (to me) belong to wordpress:

for example:

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', array( $this, 'filterRowActions' ) );
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array( $this, 'addAccommodationsFilter' ) );
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array( $this, 'fillDependencedData' ) );
```